# Python detect mouseclick on Mac

Tags: python-2.7, tkinter, mouseevent

I cant seem to find any simple explanation online or in documentation. All I want to know is how would i detect if the mouse was clicked (leftclick) while inside a tkinter GUI on a MAC and place a dot where it was clicked.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: The first step before asking such a basic question is to work through a tkinter tutorial. This is such a fundamental feature I'm almost certain it's covered in every single tutorial.

Comment: @BryanOakley is there any tutorial you would recommend?